# MongoLab strategies for restoring a database that has people currently using it

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, mlab, database

My site runs on MongoDB and I'm using MongoLab as a host for the database. I have 10-15 people using the site at any given time and would rather not 'switch them off' if at all possible.

If I have a MongoDB dump that I'd like to restore, it takes a very long time (the file size is around 360mb and this takes a good while to upload on my connection speed). What's more, it appears that MongoDB wants me to delete my collection before doing a restore, so the user would have no data to look through while it's updating.

Is there any way around this, besides, say, having two mongoLab accounts, one 'active' and one for uploading backups and I switch between the two when I need to do a restore?

Is there a general recommended strategy for this sort of thing?

Comment: Can you restore into a different collection(s), and then rename?

Comment: i'm not too sure what you're trying to do. if you email us at support@mongolab.com we'd be happy to help!

Comment: How are you restoring your database? `mongorestore` doesn't require you to delete your collection before restoring so I suspect that constraint might be something to do with the MongoLab UI? You should be able to restore in smaller batches rather than doing the full 360mb in one go. If your upload speed is a limiting factor, you could also upload to an intermediate host with better connectivity.